# Javascript: Object Model Dynamic Value at runtime

Tags: javascript, variables, object

I wish to add an object model to a Google chart dynamically at runtime. I call a php function using AJAX to get the data and based on the number of columns, I wish to make the last column a line chart.

I wish to replace 5 by c as per below script.

```
c = data.getNumberOfColumns()-2

var options = { 
   width: 400, 
   height: 240, 
   seriesType: "bars", 
   series: {5: {type: "line"}}, 
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c = data.getNumberOfColumns()-2;

var options = { 
   width: 400, 
   height: 240, 
   seriesType: "bars", 
   series: {}
 };

 options.series[c] = {type: "line"};
```